# convex and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

first i'm sorry for my bad english.
Given a function $f:(0,1)->\mathbb{R}$ which is bounded above and midpoint-convex. Is f convex and continous? (Additional question: is f constant ?)
I don't have any idea to proof it in an elementary way. First of all maybe it's easier to show convexity and then that f is continous.. 
Maybe the claim follows from Bernsein-Doetsch-Theorem (..cheating...):
http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~demmath/archive/dm45_1/5.pdf
can you help me?
litllecherry

supplement: I know that  $g:\mathbb{R}->\mathbb{R}$, bounded above and convex $=>$ g constant. Maybe can I use it because (0,1) is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ ? (if f is constant, then f is especially continous) and the only thing to proof is convexity.

Comment: The claim does indeed follow from Bernstein-Doetsch theorem. Did somebody assure you that it can be proven by a different way than the way the Bernstein-Doetsch theorem was proven?

Comment: on demand I was told that it can be proven by a different way... (I don't know  Bernsein-Doetsch-Theorem's proof exactly)

Comment: If it is constant, it is linear. If it is linear, it is also both convex and concave. Done.

Comment: but convexity has to be a requirement ? I mean first I have to show: $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ bounded above and midpoint-conex is convex, second: i know that f is constant .. or what do you mean?

Comment: is my supplement correct?